# How do I get a total amount in the footer of my ListView? VB.NET2010

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview

this is my first time posting on stackoverflow and I hope to get some help!

I'm creating a programme in VB for a cafe to total the prices of an order.

I got 12 buttons each which hold a value of a food and their individual price. When the button is clicked it shows in the listview with the quantity and the subtotal. eg. If button1 (Ham) is clicked, in the listview it will show button1, 0.8 (the price), 1 (quantity) and the subtotal (price*quantity) Same for button2 etc.

When the customer has selected the amount of items they would like, I want it to show a running total in the footer of the Listview. I want it to automatically change when another button is clicked without clicking a total button.7

I hope I explained this well enough =S

Code for the buttons below (each button has the same code but just with different names)

```
Private Sub btnHam_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnHam.Click

    Me.quantityHam = Me.quantityHam + 1
    Dim str(4) As String
    Dim item As ListViewItem

    str(0) = "Ham, Egg and Chips"
    str(1) = 4.5
    str(2) = Me.quantityHam.ToString()
    str(3) = str(1) * str(2)

    Dim WholeString As String = str(0)

    item = New ListViewItem(str)
    For maindish As Integer = 0 To Me.ListView1.Items.Count - 1

        If (Me.ListView1.Items(maindish).ToString = "ListViewItem: {" + WholeString + "}") Then
            Me.ListView1.Items.RemoveAt(maindish)
            Me.ListView1.Items.Add(item)
            Return

        End If

    Next

    Me.ListView1.Items.Add(item)

End Sub
```

Comment: Turn on `Option Strict` and fix the things like `= str(1) * str(2)`  Then explain what you mean by "footer" - you might be missing a tag (Winforms, andriod etc)

Answer (score 0):

This solution presupposes that your buttons have text with a single word, a space and the price. You'll have to adjust the details if that's not the case. You only need a single sub that `Handles` all your button click events like this:

```
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click, Button3.Click, Button4.Click, Button5.Click
    'append to underlying order
    Dim bText As String = TryCast(sender, Button).Text
    If order.ContainsKey(bText) Then
        order(bText) += 1
    Else
        order.Add(bText, 1)
    End If
    'display order to listview
    ListView1.Clear()
    For Each kvp In order
        ListView1.Items.Add(String.Format("{1}{0}{2}{0}{3}", "    ", kvp.Key.Split(" ").First, kvp.Value, Convert.ToDouble(kvp.Key.Split(" ").Last) * kvp.Value))
    Next
    ListView1.Items.Add("Total: " & Aggregate kvp In order Into Sum(Convert.ToDouble(kvp.Key.Split(" ").Last) * kvp.Value))
End Sub
```

Order is a dictionary declared at the top of the class like:

```
Dim order As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
```

This is along the lines of what you're aiming for, right?